# How can I prevent Tkinter from passing the event object in a binding? Is there any workaround to do this?

Tags: python-2.7, events, tkinter, event-binding

I want to bind a method to an event using Tkinter, but I don't need the event object passed by the 'bind'-method.
Some code for clarity:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def callback(event):
    print 'clicked!'

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind('<Button-1>', callback)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Here, the argument event in callback is unnecessary. Is there any solution or workaround to prevent the bind-method from passing the event object?

What I mean is, can i call this:

```
def callback2():
    print 'clicked!'
```

in a binding? Something like:

```
frame.bind('<Button-2>', callback2)
```

(which is actually not working, because bin passes event, but callback2 takes no arguments).

Comment: You can't prevent it passing the event, but why not just ignore it? You could consider writing e.g. a decorator function to ignore the argument for you, but that seems unnecessary.

Comment: Because I think this looks aweful. Also, PyCharm creates a warning for the unused element, and I just dont like it if there are warnings in my projects.

Comment: By convention, you would name an unused parameter `_`; I believe PyCharm also respects this. Again, if you really hate it, just wrap the callback (e.g. `frame.bind('...', lambda event: callback2())`, or write an actual decorator and use e.g. `@no_event`).

Comment: Okay, got that and it's working. Just missed something when i tried to use a lamda instead, so it threw an error.. was kinda pretty dumb. Could you do me a favor and write this as an answer, so I can accept it and close this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have three broad options, as I see it (in order of increasing complexity):

1. Use the ignored-by-convention variable name `_`:

   ```
   def callback2(_):
       ...
   ```
2. Wrap the callback when you bind it:

   ```
   frame.bind('...', lambda event: callback2())
   ```
3. Write a decorator to ignore the `event` parameter for you:

   ```
   def no_event(func):
       @functools.wraps(func)
       def wrapper(event):
           return func()
       return wrapper
   ```

   then apply it to callback methods that don't need the event:

   ```
   @no_event
   def callback2():
       ...
   ```